# Using several local SOCKS proxy tunnel for the same JVM

Tags: java, jvm, socks

I have two proxy tunnels running, one on port 1080 and one on port 1090.
I provide the 1080 proxy to the JVM using `-DsocksProxyHost=locahost -DsocksProxyPort=1080`
But I was wondering how you can provide multiple tunnels to the JVM at once.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the code that decides for any given connection which of the two SOCKS connections is to be used.  That code goes in a ProxySelector which you need to register in your application at start up time.  This cannot be done using properties alone.

See the official documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html for details on how to do it in Java 8.